# jQuery - d3.v3.min.js error 404 while building Spring Boot and Neo4j app

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring-boot, d3.js, neo4j

I'm trying to make application with Spring Boot, Neo4j and jQuery. For that I used Neo4j example project from github, but I'm getting error in those lines:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        function showMovie(title) {
            $.get("/movies/search/findByTitle?title=" + encodeURIComponent(title), // todo fix paramter in SDN
                    function (data) {
                        if (!data) return;
                        var movie = data;
                        $("#title").text(movie.title);
                        $("#poster").attr("src","/posters/"+encodeURIComponent(movie.title)+".jpg");
                        var $list = $("#crew").empty();
                        movie.roles.forEach(function (cast) {
                            $.get(cast._links.person.href, function(personData) {
                                var person = personData.name;
                                var job = cast.job || "acted";
                                $list.append($("<li>" + person + " " +job + (job == "acted"?" as " + cast.roles.join(", ") : "") + "</li>"));
                            });
                        });
                    }, "json");
            return false;
        }
</script>
```

I'm getting error 404 when trying to use two first scripts. I'm running this project on my local server.

EDIT.

Here is response with an error:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js` for the jQuery src url? Can you add the 404 error message? It should provide some details.

Comment: @Sebastian yes, I have tried that. I've edited question and added some more details

Comment: Ok, the error is related to your local setup. The url `localhost:8081/movies/search/findByTitleLike` does not exist. Can you add your Spring Controllers?